# Unable to fix VirtualBox and / or reinstall it

Tags: virtualbox, installation, virtualization, uninstall

I installed Virtual Box on Windows 7 Ultimate x64 and then I **upgraded** my system to Windows 10.

VirtualBox did work properly with both versions of Windows and I was able to run everything perfectly.

Today I did the **downgrade** to **Windows 7** again and I can't open VirtualBox anymore because I get this error:

```
Failed to create COM object

Callee RC: REGDB_E_CLASSNOTREG” (0x80040154)
```

*I tried to reinstall* it but I get some error messages telling me that I need to choose a different path and that I cannot uninstall the previous version.

***How can I fix it or reinstall it?***

---

### edit:

Since I wasn't able to uninstall it normally because the path wasn't on C:, I deleted the folder "Virtual Box" with all the files, but I got the same errors

[image: error screenshot]

---

### edit 2:

***I also did the following procedure:***

1. Open command prompt as administrator
2. Run the command:

   ```
   md `cd D:\Unknown\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Temp`
   ```
3. Open **%temp%**
4. Delete everything I was able to remove in this folder (**I couldn't delete FXSAPIDebugLogFile** because an error message told me it was already opened in file manager)
5. Download VirtualBox version 5.0.8
6. Run the **VirtualBox installer** for VERSION 5.0.8. and I got the **errors** described previously (see the screenshot) as soon as it opened
7. I tried opening `%temp%\VirtualBox\` but **I couldn't find** it .

---

### edit 3:

- I performed some of the previous steps (3 through 8) by using a second device with Win 8.1 installed to get the .msi file;
- I performed steps 1 through 4 on the PC I'm trying to reinstall VirtualBox;
- **I copy-pasted** the `%temp%\VirtualBox\VirtualBox-5.0.8-r103449-MultiArch_amd64.msi` file from the second device to the folder `D:\Unknown\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Temp` on my Win 7 PC;
- I run the installer for VirtualBox 5.0.14 and finally **I succeeded in installing** it, but now **when I open the new VirtualBox I get this error again**

  ```
  Failed to create COM object

  Callee RC: REGDB_E_CLASSNOTREG” (0x80040154)
  ```

Comment: Have you tried a fresh install? (e.g. Completely uninstall it, then re-install)

Comment: No, because I installed it on the second internal hard disk and so revo uninstaller and the tool in the control panel are unable to uninstall it...

Comment: Then just remove that folder and install it again. Should be working.

Comment: I did it but I didn't solve the issue..

Comment: If you re-run the installer does it give you the choice to uninstall it?

Comment: No, it does not...

Comment: @robertalrp you could try reg crawler to search for all registry entries related to it and delete them, I've had varied success over the years doing this in relation to a whole range of software

Comment: I fixed all the registry errors found by ccleaner and registry cleaner by glary utilities but I got the same errors while trying to reinstall Virtual Box...

Comment: @robertalrp I think you'll still find stuff using reg crawler

Comment: @CraigLowe I googled Reg crawler and find many similarly named programs but not the correct one:/ could you link me where I can get this tool, please?

Comment: @robertalrp let me have a look, I have a copy in my repair utilities but I haven't actually worked as a techy for over a year

Comment: @CraigLowe : maybe is it [this one](http://download.chip.eu/en/Registry-Crawler-4.5_32161.html) ?

Comment: @robertalrp completely forgot about this, very sorry. Yes that is it, run a search for virtual box and any derivatives of that you can think of then delete them, do a system restore point first though.

Comment: thanks (actually I just did it but there are some entries that I cannot delete...)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If running the installer again does not give you the choice to uninstall VirtualBox, let's try to manually remove it (folders, drivers, and registry entries).

Create a system restore point

Close VirtualBox (kill any VirtualBox related processes)

Confirm that you have deleted C:\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox

Delete the following files:

1. C:\Windows\System32\Drivers\vboxdrv.sys
2. C:\Windows\System32\Drivers\vboxnetadp.sys
3. C:\Windows\System32\Drivers\VBoxNetAdp6.sys
4. C:\Windows\System32\Drivers\vboxnetflt.sys (You may not have this driver depending on what version of VirtualBox you previously installed)
5. C:\Windows\System32\Drivers\vboxusbmon.sys
6. C:\Windows\System32\Drivers\vboxusb.sys (You may not have this driver depending on what version of VirtualBox you previously installed)

In the registry navigate to HKLM\System\CurrentControlSet\Services.

Delete the following keys:

1. VBoxDrv
2. VBoxNetAdp
3. VboxNetFit
4. VBoxNetLwf
5. VBoxUSBMon
6. VBoxUSB (You may not have this key depending on what version of VirtualBox you previously installed)

Restart your computer

Download the newest version of VirtualBox

Install VirtualBox

**Additional Instructions 1**

Run Command Prompt as Administrator
Run the following commands

```
cd "C:\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox"
VBoxSVC /ReRegServer
regsvr32 VBoxC.dll
```

Delete the folder C:\Users\.VirtualBox

Try to run VirtualBox

**Additional Instructions 2**

1. Open Command Prompt as Administrator
2. Run the command below:

   md "C:\users\unknown\appdata\local\temp"
3. Open %temp%
4. Delete everything in this folder
5. Download VirtualBox version 5.0.8 (http://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/5.0.8/VirtualBox-5.0.8-103449-Win.exe)
6. Close all other programs
7. Run the VirtualBox installer for **VERSION 5.0.8**. As soon as you get to the first screen that says welcome **STOP**.
8. Open %temp%\VirtualBox\
9. Copy %temp%\VirtualBox\VirtualBox-5.0.8-r103449-MultiArch_amd64.msi to C:\Users\UNKNOWN\AppData\Local\Temp\
10. Delete the files in %temp%
11. Now close everything
12. Run the VirtualBox installer for **VERSION 5.0.14**

If that fixes the problem, then when it is done and you restart your computer, you can safely delete C:\Users\Unknown. You can delete the files in %temp% again too.

Comment: Thank you. I did everything that you suggested but nothing changed, I got the same errors...

Comment: Does C:\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox exist again after trying to reinstall?

Comment: If C:\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox exists after you reinstall VirtualBox please perform the steps offered in Additional Instructions 1.

Comment: VirtualBox was installed on D:\00_PROGRAMMI\Program Files (x86) and no, it does not exist there after trying to reinstall.

Comment: I'm going to do some research tonight and get back to you. I think you have a CLSID that needs removed.

Comment: Alright, so I downloaded and installed the same version of VirtualBox you are trying to install and then deleted the files I suggested you delete and tried to uninstall it. It worked for me. I looked at what changes are made to the registry when you install VirtualBox and there are over 2000. So I took a look at your screenshot again and wanted to try something different. Please refer to Additional Instructions 2.

Comment: Thanks, I tryed to do those steps but I got errors again. I updated my question with the results of the procedure.

Comment: Can you do steps 3-8 on a different computer? What we are trying to do is get the MSI file it is looking for and put it in the folder it is looking for it in.

Comment: I hold a tablet running Win 8.1 which has VirtualBox already installed and working, configured to run Whonix inside, like the version installed on my Win 7 laptop. I did the steps 1, 2, 3, 4. I did step 8 but couldn't find any folder containing VirtualBox

Comment: Really what you need to do is steps 3 through 8 not 1 through 4. What we are trying to do is copy the MSI that your computer is looking for by running the old installer so it drops the MSI in %temp%\VirtualBox.

Comment: Ok, I got the file **.msi** from the second device and I'm ready to copy it, I'm on my pc now. However the folder _C:\Users\UNKNOWN\AppData\Local\Temp\_  doesn't exist.
 I also check  _D:\Unknown\AppData\Local_  but there is no  _Temp_  folder there.

Comment: That is true (I think you skipped a step :) ). On the computer you are trying to install VirtualBox performs steps 1 through 4, then copy the .msi to C:\Users\UNKNOWN\AppData\Local\Temp\ and do steps 10 through 12.

Comment: thanks, I succeded in installing it again, but now I get the error again when I open it (I described it in my question) :(

Comment: Did you copy the 5.0.8 MSI or the 5.0.14 MSI?

Comment: the 5.0.8 .msi (the file you linked to me)

Comment: If you were able to install 5.0.8 you should be able to uninstall both.

Comment: I did the steps again and I succeded in uninstalling VirtualBox. Although I did a fresh installation now I get the error again:/ (Failed to create COM object...)

Comment: So we fixed your second problem, but not your first problem.

The good and still bad new is that you aren't alone. There is an open ticket with VirtualBox for the error you have (https://www.virtualbox.org/ticket/14296).

Are you a local admin? Did you run the VirtualBox 5.0.14 installer as an admin?

Comment: yes, I did run it both as local and as Admin